# Fingerprint matching using wave files

Tags: java, android, musicg

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.musicg.fingerprint.FingerprintSimilarity;
import com.musicg.wave.Wave;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FingerprintSimilarity fingerprintsimilarity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Wave wave =new Wave("raw/test.wav");
    Wave wave1=new Wave("raw/test.wav");
    fingerprintsimilarity = wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave1);
    float score = fingerprintsimilarity.getScore();
    float similarity = fingerprintsimilarity.getSimilarity();
    Log.d("HI", "Score : " + score + "\n Similarity : " + similarity);

}
}
```

Implementing musicg for fingerprint matching following error occurs :

> 06-12 12:06:41.921 20132-20132/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>       06-12 12:06:42.023 20132-20132/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching-2/lib/arm64
>       06-12 12:06:42.037 20132-20132/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>       06-12 12:06:42.098 20132-20132/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>       06-12 12:06:42.191 20132-20132/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: raw/test.wav (No such file or
>   directory)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:99)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.musicg.wave.Wave.(Wave.java:60)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: raw/test.wav (No such file or
>   directory)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:99)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.musicg.wave.Wave.(Wave.java:60)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
>       06-12 12:06:42.192 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       06-12 12:06:42.193 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>       06-12 12:06:42.193 20132-20132/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>       06-12 12:06:42.195 20132-20132/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       06-12 12:06:42.195 20132-20132/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                          Process: com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching, PID: 20132
>                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching/com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   com.musicg.wave.WaveHeader.getSampleRate()' on a null object reference
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
>                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   com.musicg.wave.WaveHeader.getSampleRate()' on a null object reference
>                                                              at com.musicg.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.extractFingerprint(FingerprintManager.java:69)
>                                                              at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprint(Wave.java:329)
>                                                              at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(Wave.java:335)
>                                                              at com.example.dhrum.fingerprintmatching.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
>                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814) 
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290) 
>                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>       06-12 12:06:42.196 20132-20132/? D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
>       06-12 12:06:42.216 20132-20132/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20132 SIG: 9

I am using mono wav files and files are in a folder named raw inside the app folder.

Comment: Can you paste the full Log?

Comment: Updated the log for further clarity...

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: raw/test.wav (No such file or directory)` .

Try this:-

```
 Wave wave =new Wave("R.raw.test"); // not ("raw/test.wav");
 Wave wave1=new Wnave("R.raw.test");
```

Since *`"test.wav"`* is a file in Android resource you have to access it this way.